# Create a SoapUI test in groovy script?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have problem with creating test via groovy script.
I need generate url in code and get response to variable.

We can use existing test by next code.

```
def testRunnerMap = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("REST Test Request")
```

Can we create test by groovy ?

please help me

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for something like below. I got this code from http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4579

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.GroovyScriptStepFactory
suite = context.testCase.testSuite.project.addNewTestSuite("ali")
tc = suite.addNewTestCase("test case ali")
gs = tc.addTestStep( GroovyScriptStepFactory.GROOVY_TYPE, "ali's GroovyScript" )
gs.properties["script"].value = 'log.info(\'hello world\')'
context.testCase.testSuite.project.save()
```